# Java service return the Result message along with Object class

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi i have to return the ResultMessage  along with my object class in my below code.

```
public List<EmployeeInformation> findAll(String IndexName) throws Exception {

        String ResultMessage = new String();
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(IndexName)) {
            ResultMessage= "Index name is null or empty";
        } else if (isTextContainUpperCase(IndexName)) {
            ResultMessage= "Index name should be in lowercase";
        } else if (!checkEsConnection(client)) {
            ResultMessage= "Elasticsearch deployment is not reachable";
        }
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(IndexName);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return getSearchResult(searchResponse);
    }



private List<EmployeeInformation> getSearchResult(SearchResponse response) {

        SearchHit[] searchHit = response.getHits().getHits();

        List<EmployeeInformation> EmployeeDocuments = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SearchHit hit : searchHit) {
            EmployeeDocuments
                    .add(objectMapper
                            .convertValue(hit
                                    .getSourceAsMap(), EmployeeInformation.class));
        }

        return EmployeeDocuments;
    }
```

What is the best way to return the ResultMessage along with my employeeinformation object. Could some one Modify the above code accordingly and post your answer or suggest me how to achieve this? thanks in advance

Comment: create a class that has the message and the data as properties and return an instance of this class

Comment: Create a `WrappedObject.class` and return that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `ImmutablePair<ResultMessage, List<EmployeeInformation>>`.
This objects then be accessed by getLeft() and getRight() methods. However, you will need `org.apache.commons` lib for this. It is worth adding this lib as it has many more such utils and wrapper classes. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

Answer (score 1):

This code is my suggested sample code for your requirement.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Test test = new Test();
        String dept = "test";

        Object[] result = test.searchUser(dept);

        // Here must and should be follow the initailize order.
        String something = null;
        EmployeeInformation employee = null;
        if (result.length>= 0 && result[0] instanceof String) {
            something = (String) result[0];
        }

        if (result.length>= 1 && result[1] instanceof EmployeeInformation) {
            employee = (EmployeeInformation) result[1];
        }
        // do something
    }

    public Object[] searchUser(String dept) {

        Object[] result = new Object[2];

        result[0] = dept;
        result[1] = getUser(dept);

        return result;

    }

    private List<EmployeeInformation> getUser(String dept) {

        List<EmployeeInformation> userList = null;

        // some logic for get the EmployeeInformationInformation List based on
        // department.

        return userList;

    }

}
```

Comment: This code is to avoid new class creation for  Every Dynamic return type.